# How to make return submit a form with a select

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

Edit: oh, I solved it. it was easier than I thought. Thanks for reading.

When you have both a `<select>` and a `<input type="submit">` in your form, hitting return won't work when the focus is on the `<select>`.

```html
<form action="nothing.html">
    <select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <input type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
```

(or as [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2xKpN/))

What would be an elegant way to make the return key behave the expected way?

I believe this is a simple problem, so it deserves a simple solution. Now I was thinking

```javascript
document.forms[0].onkeypress = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) this.submit();
}
```

but that was too simple, apparently. Any ideas?

Edit:
Sorry, not enough information. This is in an ASP.NET web application, where the form gets submitted to itself, not to another web page. So although the `submit` function does indeed work as such, the server doesn't know what to do with the submitted stuff and the button click event handler won't be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aw, that was too easy. Instead of `form.submit()`, just do a `button.click()`. Sorry for wasting your time all you reading this.